# How to catch an click event on pagination buttons next/previous of the DataTables Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable, pagination, angular-datatables

How to catch click event in pagination buttons previous/next in angular 5. unfortunately I got the code in jquery.

### jquery code:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
 drawCallback: function(){
  $('.paginate_button.next', this.api().table().container())          
  .on('click', function(){
  alert('next');
 });       
 }
});
```

[#stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42164402/4544989)

[#jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ajbghfhh/)

But I need angular data table. If you have an example, how to catch the previous/next click event.

Button Row Click event

```
 buttonInRowClick(event: any): void {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Button in the row clicked.');
  }
```

Whole Row Click Event

```
wholeRowClick(): void {
    console.log('Whole row clicked.');
  }
```

Expecting next/previous button click event

```
nextButtonClickEvent():void {
   //do next particular records like  101 - 200 rows.
   //we are calling to api
}
previousButtonClickEvent():void {
  //do previous particular the records like  0 - 100 rows.
   //we are calling to API
}
```

Because I have thousands of records in my backend.

Comment: can you share some code about what you want related to angular ??

Comment: Hi, @malbarmawi thanks for quick response. I added updated sample code in the angular data table. kindly check [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/ajbghfhh/) once. he has done in jquery

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using ngx-datatable library, very complete and easy to use ! Even the documentation is good ! https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable

Comment: C thanks for the response ngx-datatable its good. But I have millions of records. initial time load only 100 filtering records like 1- 100, when I click the next button. I expect only next 100 records like 101 - 200. ngx-datatable not supported

Comment: ngx-datatable also supports server-side paging, passing the page id (don't know if your API was built this way :) ) : http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#server-paging

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use event delegation by providing selector for target element as a second argument in on() call, see example below. According to jQuery on() documentation

Comment: send me some example in angular2 code, not a jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a reference to your Angular component about the element that you are going to bind the functionality

```
<div #mytable></div>
```

In your component add an element reference with ViewChild

```
@ViewChild('mytable') tableRef: ElementRef;
```

Then use that element reference to bind the functionality that you want and make it accessible in angular

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.table = $(this.tableRef.nativeElement).DataTable({
      drawCallback: function () {
        $('.paginate_button.next', this.api().table().container()).on('click', () =>  {
          // your angular method here
          this.nextButtonClickEvent();
        });
      }
  });
}
```

Just test your scope. By using arrow functions you can access the methods written in you class and that should do the trick

Comment: Hi, @Antonis i got error ERROR `TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`

Comment: that pretty much means that 'tableRef' is undefined.
did you add :

`@ViewChild('mytable') tableRef: ElementRef;`

in your class?

Comment: yes @Antonis, I added your code. `@ViewChild('mytable') tableRef: ElementRef;`. but i got undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any jquery code inside you component and use arrow function to maintain reference to `this`

*component*

```
declare let $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {


  ngOnInit() {
    let table = $('#example').DataTable({
      drawCallback: () => {
        $('.paginate_button.next')
          .on('click', () => {
            this.nextButtonClickEvent();
          });
      }
    });
  }

  nextButtonClickEvent(): void {
       console.log('next clicked');
  }

}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9k31k2)

Comment: thanks for your effort, I didn't get any error, I didn't get `next clicked`. I am using angular 5 your using angular 6

Comment: It 's will work in all version and you can see in the stackblitz demo ,is it working in your project ? @Senthil

Comment: I saw your stackblitz demo. In my project not working your code

Comment: what kind of error did you get  and did you check that you change function to arrow function

Comment: I am using angular-datable plugins. show i got warning error **DataTables warning: table id={id} - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.**  my code `<table id="geotesting" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger">`  [npm angular-datatables](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-datatables)

Comment: [documentation link](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) and [github issue link](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/1313)

Comment: thanks for your quick response.this is  [l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/row-click-event](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/row-click-event) **row click event**. I am asking **pagination next/previous click event**